# How to remove text after alpha characters in python?

Tags: python

So I have strings like:

```
FirstName LastName - SomeText
FirstName LastName / SomeMoreText
```

I was wondering how to remove everything after a character that is not in the alphabet?

Thanks

Comment: please provide the code you have and a minimally reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: what do you mean after a character that is not in the alphabet? for example after .?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a perfect use case for Regex. Python's `re` library provides a `.split` command, which does exactly what you want.

The regex string `[^a-zA-Z\s]` matches everything that isn't alphabet characters (`a-zA-Z`) or whitespace (`\s`) by using the negate character `^`. Then, you pass `maxsplit=1` to the split command since you only want the first group resulting from the split.

```py
import re

data = [
    "FirstName LastName - SomeText",
    "FirstName LastName / SomeMoreText"
]

for string in data:
    split = re.split(r"[^a-zA-Z\s]", string, maxsplit=1)
    result = split[0]
    print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
a_string = "ab-cd"

split_string = a_string.split("-", 1)

substring = split_string[0]

print(substring)
```

if you need specific answer, then you've to give more description

Comment: The question specifically asks how to split on non-alphabetic characters, not a single explicit character like `-`.

Answer (score 0):

```
sentense="abcdώdfgdfg"
result=""
validchars="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
validchars+=validchars.upper()

for letter in sentense:
    if letter in validchars:
        result=result+letter
    else:
        break
print(result)
```

it checks all letter from the sentense and if is in valid letters it is added to resul else it stops and displays the final result

Answer (score 0):

This should work - just add whatever chars you want to `chars`:

```py
txt = "some?text"
chars = ["?","!","&","-","+","#",")","(","[","]"]
for char in chars:
    if char in txt:
        splittxt = txt.split(char)[0]
```

This builds off of https://stackoverflow.com/a/68041566/16263236, but adds support for more chars.

Comment: What if `txt` contains `)`? Or `(`? Or `#`? This shouldn't be solved by explicitly specifying non-alpha characters.

Comment: @Spooky I can add those chars. However, probably https://stackoverflow.com/a/68041650/16263236 would work better if wider support is needed